# How to get a C++ pair to compile

Tags: c++, std-pair

I am trying to compile a very complicated code and I get the error

```
g++ -o MCBody MCBody.cpp
MCBody.cpp:36:34: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 double numericalIntegration::pair<double,double> integrate(double (*pFun)(const double & x),const double & LBound, const double & UBound)
```

You can see that here is a problem with the recognition of the C++ `pair` object. I am too stupid to see what is wrong and cannot make the code very smaller. I want your help with respect.

Here is MCBody.cpp (the big one):

```
//---MCBody---//
// Function that performs a regular numeric integration by with random
// spacing between points and unit weighting. Tells the
// NumericalIntegration class what the functions are to do.
// INPUTS (for integrate):
// Fun = a function of x
// LBound = lower bound of integral
// UBound = upper bound of integral
// OUTPUT:
// IntDev = a pair with the first value being the integral and the second
// being the standard deviation.

#ifndef MCRULE_CPP                      // If Monte Carlo rule is not 
#define MCRULE_CPP                      // defined, define it.

#include "NumericalIntegrationClass.h"  // So it can see the class def.
#include <stdlib.h>                     // For rand and srand
#include <time.h>                       // Get random srand values.
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


// I: Tell the integration what the number of intervals/points taken are.
numericalIntegration::numericalIntegration(const int & numIntervals)
{
  // THIS is a pointer to the current object within a member function. It
  // is used when no other object name is specified.
  this->numIntervals = numIntervals;  // Stores the value of the
                                      // parameter numIntervals.
}


// II: Perform the integration approximation.
double numericalIntegration::pair<double,double> integrate(double (*pFun)(const double & x),const double & LBound, const double & UBound)
{
  // Return value is different to one stored in location pointed by time.
  srand(time(NULL)); 
  double XintSize = (UBound-LBound);
  double Total = 0;
  double SumOSquares = 0;

  for (int i =0; i<=numIntervals; i++)
    {
      // Creating 'random' points within the lower bound and upper bound.
      double x_i = LBound + (rand())/ (RAND_MAX/XintSize);

      // Evaluate the pointer at x_i and add to Total.
      double fx = (*pFun)(x_i);
      Total += fx;
      SumOSquares += pow(fx,2);
    }  
  double Deviation = SumOSquares - pow(Total,2);
  Deviation = (sqrt(Deviation))/((float)numIntervals+1);
  double Integral = (1/((float)numIntervals+1))*XintSize*Total;
  pair<double,double> IntDev;

  IntDev =  make_pair(Integral,Deviation);

  return IntDev;
}

#endif
```

Here is MCRule.cpp:

```
//---MCRule---//
// A function to calculate the integral of a function via the Monte Carlo
// method.
// INPUTS:
// n = number of points
// l = lower limit of the integration
// u = upper limit of the integration
// line 24: the function to be integrated

// I: Define a function that is supposed to be integrated.
#include "NumericalIntegrationClass.h" // Want to include a reference to
                                       // the header in the main file so 
                                       // it can see what's happening in
                                       // the class.
#include <math.h>                      // Cos.
#include "MCBody.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

double fun(const double & x)  // Passing a reference to some number x
{                             // (not going to change x within the loop).
                              // Passing by reference, therefore not
                              // allocating any new space.
  // Define the function to be integrated.
   return ((1 + 0.25*cos(x))/(1+x*x)); 
   //return (1+0.25*cos(tan(x)));

}

// II: Execute Monte Carlo integration function.
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) // First bit = counts the arguments.
                                  // Sec bit = the vector that stores the
                                  // arguments.
{
  // Retrieve inputs.
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);     // Extracts number of points.
  double l = atoi(argv[2]);  // Extracts lower bound for integration.
  double u = atoi(argv[3]);  // Extracts upper bound for integration.

  // Define number of intervals.
  numericalIntegration numInt(n);

  // Define lower and upper bounds for integral.
  pair<double,double> IntDev = numInt.integrate(fun,l,u);
  float abso = fabs(IntDev.first - 3.2294), rel = (abso/IntDev.first)*100;
  cout << "Integral is: " << IntDev.first << endl;
  cout << "Absolute Error: " << abso << endl;
  cout << "Relative Error: " << rel << "%" << endl;
  cout << "Standard Deviation: " << IntDev.second << endl;
  cout << "Monte Carlo Error: " << IntDev.second/(sqrt(n+1)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is NumericalIntegrationClass.h:

```
//---NumericalIntegrationClass---//
// Creates a class of for functions which can be integrated using the
// Monte Carlo method.
// This class has 2 public functions; one which points the class to the 
// number of points/intervals used (numericalIntegration), and one used
// to perform the actual integration approximation.

// I: PRE-PROCESSORS
#pragma once   // Current source file to be included once in a single
               // compilation. Serves same purpose of #include guard but
               // avoids name clashes.
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


class numericalIntegration
{
  // II: DEFINE PUBLIC
  // Public area can be touched from outside of the function.
 public:   

  // NUMERICALINTEGRATION: Setting the number of intervals to be a 
  // constant integer.
  numericalIntegration(const int & numIntervals);

  // INTEGRATE: Call the method that calculates the value of the 
  // integral.
  pair<double,double> integrate(double (*pFun)(const double & x),const double & LBound, const double & UBound);


  // III: DEFINE PRIVATE
  // Private area can only be touched by internal methods.
 private:   
  int numIntervals;
};
```

Comment: `numericalIntegration::` should stick to `integrate`, not to `pair`

Comment: I dont't quite understand the purpose of `double numericalIntegration::pair<double,double> integrate(double (*pFun)(const double & x),const double & LBound, const double & UBound)` - apparently a method `integrate` of `numericalIntegration` is about to be defined, the return type would be `double` - what is the purpose of the pair?

Comment: `double numericalIntegration::pair<double,double> integrate(` <- you are saying `pair` is in `numericalIntegration` and `integrate` is a free function. (and the `double` is extra junk).

Comment: Look at the line the compiler prints out. Read it from the left to the right. Try to work out what it says. Compare that with what you intended it to say. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numericalIntegration::pair<double,double>
```

This means:

1. go to the `numericalIntegration` class
2. find its `pair` member
3. make sure it is a template that accepts two type arguments
4. and instantiate it with `<double, double>` arguments

This fails at #2 as there is no `pair` member in `numericalIntegration`. There is a member named `integrate` that returns `std::pair<double, double>`. To express that in C++, you say

```
pair<double,double> numericalIntegration::integrate
```

Comment: The need for the member pair defined is what I did not understand. Thank you very much. :)